# Unable to use Python2 in Jupyter Notebook: Python in worker has different version 2.7 than that in driver 3.4

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

My knowledge with Jupyter and python is limited. You can sense it after reading this question. I have two set of servers: one set of servers running the spark-standalone cluster and one server running the Jupyter notebook.

I have installed Jupyter in my server twice with commands:

```
pip2 install jupyter
pip3 install jupyter
```

After installing I set the following environments:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --notebook-dir=./ --ip=* --no-browser"
```

Then I used Jupyter to connect to the spark-standalone cluster with the following command:

```
./bin/pyspark --master spark://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:7077
```

I can login in the Jupyter homepage in my laptop and in the right corner the message indicates that I am using Python2. However, I cannot execute Python2 codes while Python3 codes work.
[image]

I tried the following command
`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2`
and
  `import os
    os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/usr/local/bin/python2"`

but with no luck.

Is this because I am using a Jupyter notebook created by pip3? If it is, how can I switch to the Jupyter notebook created by pip2?

Thanks in advance if you have any suggestions. If you need more information to locate the cause, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this problem aside these days and picked it again today. To determine whether spark or jupyter was responsible for this problem, I launched the Jupyter Notebook without spark: `jupyter notebook`. The same problem arose again so I knew there was something wrong with my Jupyter Notebook.

I referred to this document: [Installing the IPython kernel](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html). After executing the following commands I could run Python2 codes.

`python2 -m pip install ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install --user`

I have tried these two commands before posting the questions but with no luck. I guess maybe I made some mistakes when coping/pasting? Anyway, the problem is now solved.